# Endpoint not found

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria, wcf-ria-services

I have created a new WCF RIA service with OData exposed. I wanted to test it out.

My project name was `ChinookSample` and the namespace was `ChinookSample.Web.Services`

When I try to browse...

> http://localhost:52878/Services/ChinookSample-Web-services-dsAlbumAndArtist.svc

I get the service page, but the moment I go for...

> http://localhost:52878/Services/ChinookSample-Web-services-dsAlbumAndArtist.svc/OData

I get `EndPoint not found`. I have checked my Web.Config and that has the OData defined.

What is the correct way to troubleshoot this?

Also, `<domainServices>` tag has a squiggly saying ... `System.ServiceModel has invalid Child element domainServices`.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got the issue resolved. I missed the trailing / in the URL ...

> http://localhost:52878/Services/ChinookSample-Web-services-dsAlbumAndArtist.svc/OData/